# PHP/Laravel - Create an array of objects from two simple arrays or an associative array that combines that two

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-5

I'm looking for a way transform a php associative array into an array of object and keying each association. I could also treat this as two separate simple arrays, one with the names and one with the classes. Here's an associative example...

```
array:2 [
  "someName" => "someClass"
  "someOtherName" => "someOtherClass"
]
```

Or

```
names => [0 => 'name1', 1 => 'name2']
classes => [0 => 'class1', 1 => 'class2']
```

...either way, I'm looking for an end result like this:

```
[
    { 'name': 'someName', 'class': 'someClass' },
    { 'name': 'someOtherName', 'class': 'someOtherClass' }
]
```

What's the smartest way to do this?

Comment: You're looking for `json_encode`?

Comment: Nope. That's just return a json encoded string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way is to combine [zip](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-zip) method with [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-transform) or [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-map):

```
$names = [0 => 'name1', 1 => 'name2'];
$classes = [0 => 'class1', 1 => 'class2'];

$merged = collect($names)->zip($classes)->transform(function ($values) {
    return [
        'name' => $values[0],
        'class' => $values[1],
    ];
});

dd($merged->all());
```

As a result you get array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "name1"
    "class" => "class1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "name2"
    "class" => "class2"
  ]
]
```

so if you need json, you can just use `json_encode($merged)`

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much 